# Why new component opening in the same page

Tags: angular, routerlink

I am new to Angular, I have created very simple application with two component, I just want to navigate from one to another.

But second components opens in same(below the 1st) component. How can I open 2nd comp. in new page?

This is my code

```
<td> <a routerLink="devicelist">Privacy Policy</a> </td>
<div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

app-route.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products.component';
import { DeviceListComponent } from './device-list/device-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'devicelist', component: DeviceListComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],

})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Edit: 1**

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products.component';
import { DeviceListComponent } from './device-list/device-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProductsComponent,
  },
  { path: 'devicelist', component: DeviceListComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comp1 file

```
<div>
    <style>
        table {
          font-family: arial, sans-serif;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          width: 100%;
        }

        td, th {
          border: 1px solid #dddddd;
          text-align: left;
          padding: 8px;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
          background-color: #dddddd;
        }
        </style>
    <table >
        <tr >
          <th>Product Name </th>
          <th>Compliance</th>
          <th>Failed</th>
          <th>Inprogress</th>
          <th>Reprocess</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>           
            <td>Connected Courrier</td>
            <td> <a routerLink="devicelist">Privacy Policy</a> </td>
            <td>Failed</td>
            <td>Inprogress</td>
            <td>Reprocess </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>           
            <td>Admin App</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>Failed</td>
            <td>Inprogress</td>
            <td>Reprocess </td>
        </tr>

      </table>

    </div>
```

Comp2 file

```
<div>
    <p>device-list works!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The router-outlet is where the current rout's component is inserted. And it's inside your first component. So when you navigate to your unique route, the second component is inserted in the first one, next to the router-outlet. If you want the first component to disappear, then the router outlet should be in your app component, and both of your other components should be the component of a route.

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser console? Does setting pathMatch: full on the empty route make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have placed  `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside the first component.so whenever you navigate to the second component it will render inside the first component.

Note: Place  `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the `app.component.html` and create two separate components then will work

Comment: I have made comp 1st as root so app.component.html ot being used, i think

Comment: router-outlet Acts as a placeholder that Angular dynamically fills based on the current router state.  https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet

Comment: Now what changes should I make as my root is 1st component

Comment: i will share an example in few minutes

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya that's what you need to change. If you only want to show something on a specific route, then it shouldn't be inside the root component, which is **always** displayed.

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya i have created simple navigation example 
 here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-navigation-basic

Comment: can you post your files in the question? post app.component.html,app.routing.module.ts,compo1.ts,compo2.ts

Comment: also post app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

Place `router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the `app.component.html`, then create 2 separate components and give the links accordingly. This will help in navigating.

Comment: I have made root my 1st component, so appComoent not being used I think. What should I do now

Comment: Can you please share your code through stackBlitz ?

Comment: Is there any facility on stackBlitz  to upload existing code?

Answer (score 0):

1. Just add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your `app.component.html`,nothing more than that.
2. Add routings in your appModule

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: 'first', component: FirstComponent},
  { path: 'second', component: SecondComponent }
])],
```